# How to get input text from soft keyboard

Tags: java, android

I am launching the soft keyboard like this:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(buttonLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

`buttonLayout` is a simple button on my UI. 
How do I extract what the user wrote (without using a `EditText` field or maybe hiding the `EditText`) so the user can't see or click on it?

Comment: Sounds like a keylogger to me :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced same issue. if i hide edit text, `edtTxt.getText().toString()` gets empty always. so i kept like

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxt"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px" />
```

So that user can't see that. and on click of button

```
edtTxt.requestFocus();
edtTxt.setText("");
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(edtTxt.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
            0);
```

Now `edtTxt.getText().toString()` giving text what I typed using keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

Without an EditText you're going to have a hard time.

An InputMethod needs to be connected to a view. Whatever view you use, you need to override `onCreateInputConnection` to return a custom `InputConnection` object that at a minimum implements commitText (for word input), `deleteSurroundingText` (for deletes), and `sendKeyEvent` (for keyboards that assume you're in dumb mode), and all of the completion functions.  Input connections are complicated things and you'll screw up 3rd party keyboards like Swiftkey and Swype if you don't get it right.  I really don't suggest doing this.

If you want to do this your best chance of getting it right is to claim your window is a `TYPE_NULL` input type.  Most keyboards will dumb themselves down and assume you only accept the simplest commands in that mode.  But you can't count on it.

I'd look at the `InputConnection` returned by the `EditText` class and copy as much of it as possible.

Comment: Could I pass it an invisible `EditText`?

Comment: I am trying to create an input field view which has a label on left and textbox to right of label. But I am trying to pull it off by extending EditText and customizing onDraw but

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan Don't do that by extending EditText.  Extend LinearLayout, and add a TextView and an EditView to it in the constructor.  Then delegate any functions you need to on the layout to the edit text.  Its much easier to do this by creating a composite than inheritance.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Creating a composite is what I ended up doing. But I rather using one view for.performance reason and also simplicity when adding it to a ViewGroup. Creating such a view is complicated, but in the end, if I need to add it to a ViewGroup all I need is new View(context); instead of inflating a ViewTree and then adding to ViewGroup.

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan That's micro-optimizing long before you ought to be worried about it.  The speed hit you'll take for adding in the extra views will be tiny.  The number of bugs and amount of time you'd lose by creating a new view will be large.  Its worth creating custom view if you need to do something unique, but not to just avoid a linear layout holding two elements.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan The learning is definitely worth it. And from my understanding of Android's view tree, the more branches the more iteration, plus function calls. As a C++ personel thats my tedency. Plus I discovered a horrible bug in my code that caused good logics to crash. It turns out I was using LayoutInflater wrong and it caused me to add an extra LinearLayout. WRONG = ViewGroup = LayoutInflator.inflate(layout,new LinearLayout()); RIGHT = ViewGroup = LayoutInflator.inflate(layout,new LinearLayout(),false);

Answer (score 2):

**I will give you a simple & short trick, Which I've tested and working very fine**

---

Create an `EditText` with `0dp` height and `0dp` width so that user won't see the `EditText` even it's visible there.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />
```

---

When The button is clicked then request focus on `EditText` and open keyboard as your own way

```
buttonLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);                inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);    
            }
        });
```

---

Then Add a `TextWatcher()` in `EditText` and additionally you can make that `EditText` invisible in `beforeTextChanged` method, it's optional. Your `TextWatcher` looks like this

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Optional
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {    
       myString = editText.getText().toString(); //Here you will get what you want          
    }
});
```